# how can I cluster images in python

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, plot, computer-vision

I'm new to machine learning and scikit-learn. but tomorrow i have to submit a task to teacher, pls help. i need to extract features from all images in specified directory, then apply PCA method to this images and create scatter plot, which shows images distribution.

should i use libraries like scikit-learn to extract those features? how can i plot 2d scatter?

i already take a look at this article https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html but still have not clear understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to cluster your images is owl-python library. You will get interactive plotly scatter. They apply resnet50 model for feature extraction and PCA (principal component analysis) you mentioned.

installation:
according to https://pypi.org/project/owl-python/

`pip install owl-python`

loading images form directory:

```
owl = Owl("/path/to/directory")
```

plotting data (kind could be 'iscatter' for interactive plot, where you could see images on hover):

```
owl.distplot(kind="scatter")
```

After this simple steps you will get pretty interactive plot.